# Is it possible to use replication between 2 different SQL Versions?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL Server 2016 database in one server and a SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition database in another server.
Is it possible to use replication and pass data from 2016 to 2019?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the [Tutorial: Prepare SQL Server for replication (publisher, distributor, subscriber)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) on the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/tutorial-preparing-the-server-for-replication?view=sql-server-ver15#prerequisites) section of the doc:

> - Replication is not supported on SQL Server instances that are more    than two versions apart. For more information, see **[Supported SQL
>   Server Versions in Replication
>   Topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15)**.

That other reference doc says:

> Backward compatibility is important to understand if you are
> upgrading, or if you have more than one version of SQL Server in a
> replication topology.
>
> The general rules are:
>
> - A Distributor can be any version as long as it is greater than or    equal to the Publisher version (in many cases the Distributor is the
>   same instance as the Publisher).
> - A Publisher can be any version as long as it less than or equal to    the Distributor version.
> - Subscriber version depends on the type of publication:
>
>   - A Subscriber to a transactional publication can be any version within    two versions of the Publisher version. For example: a SQL
>     Server 2012    (11.x) Publisher can have SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and
>     SQL Server 2016    (13.x) Subscribers; and a SQL Server 2016 (13.x)
>     Publisher can have    SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and SQL Server 2012
>     (11.x) Subscribers.
>   - A Subscriber to a merge publication can be all versions equal to or    lower than the Publisher version which are supported as per the
>     versions life cycle support cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case it *generally* is. Typically as long as the Publishing server is the same or less version than the server hosting the Distributor, you should be ok. Specifically SQL Server 2016 can be a Publisher to a SQL Server 2019 Subscriber server, if you're using Transactional or Snapshot replication. Merge replication is not compatible though.

Please see the [Replication Backwards Compatibility - Replication Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-backward-compatibility?view=sql-server-ver15#replication-matrix) for specific version compatibility information across the different types of replication.

Comment: what if we have MS SQL server 2014 and 2019, can we use replication?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Which one would be the Publisher?

Comment: MSSQL 2014 version is Publisher.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir It'll likely be ok, but you'll have to try it out to know for sure. BTW, 2014 is no longer supported by Microsoft, and even 2016 isn't too far behind it, you should definitely upgrade the 2014 instance as soon as possible.