# Adding a Windows Server 2016 computer to a Windows Server 2022 Failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, windows-server

Is it possible to join a Windows Server 2016 computer to an existing Windows Server 2022 2-node Failover cluster? The cluster is domain-independent.

Hypothetical setup:

1. Node 1 (windows server 2022 + Sql Server 2022)
2. Node 2 (windows server 2022 + Sql Server 2022)
   Nodes 1 and 2 will be in a failover cluster
3. Node 3 (windows server 2016 + Sql Server 2016)

My goal is to join the Windows Server 2016 computer running SQL Server 2016 to a Windows Server 2022 Failover cluster running SQL Server 2022. This will be an Always On Availability Group setup.

Once Node 1 and 2 are synchronized with Node 3, I plan to failover to Node 1 and remove node 3 from the cluster.

Comment: I would suggest the another way. Create the AG on 2022 and a mirror of the database to this AG or use a log shipping, then you cut the connection and change application configuration (which ha to be done anyway) This way you do not have any issues with different Windows versions in a cluster.

Comment: Is that intended to migrate your data from SQL Server 2016 to a brand new SQL Server 2022 with no/little downtime? Plese, see if [Is possible to Use Replication between 2 different SQL Versions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310277/is-possible-to-use-replication-between-2-different-sql-versions/310279#310279) is of any help.

Comment: I looked into the suggested link but SQL Server 2016 and 2022 and too far apart to support a publisher-subscriber topology. Regarding the db mirroring approach, I have no experience with that technology. I considered the log shipping approach, but that will require a bit more downtime for the tail-end of the log to be taken and restored. Still, it's probably the safest option since the different Windows versions in a cluster may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to join a Windows Server 2016 computer to an existing Windows Server 2022 2-node Failover cluster?

No, it is not. The cluster is already at a higher functional level and lower level nodes cannot be added.

Attempts to add a node will result in a incompatible OS check when adding the node.

`The node failed to join the cluster because the joining node and other nodes in the cluster have incompatible operating system versions.`

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about **adding** a new node with older Windows version to the cluster, but the state of having a cluster with different versions is possible, according to the [Cluster operating system rolling upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/cluster-operating-system-rolling-upgrade#cluster-transition-states-during-cluster-os-rolling-upgrade) doc:

> In order to keep the cluster workloads running during the Cluster OS
> Rolling Upgrade process, moving a cluster workload from a node running
> an older version of Windows Server to a node running a newer version
> of Windows Server works by using a compatibility mode. This
> compatibility mode makes the nodes running the newer version of
> Windows Server appear as if they are running the the same older
> version of Windows Server. For example, when upgrading a Windows
> Server 2016 cluster to Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2019 nodes
> operate in a Windows Server 2016 compatibility mode as a temporary
> measure. A new conceptual cluster mode, called mixed-OS mode, allows
> nodes of different versions to exist in the same cluster (see Figure
> 1).
>
> [image: Cluster with different Windows versions]